# How to send Headers in Android

Tags: android, http-headers, shoutcast

Thanks to all of you in advance :)

I want to send Headers in android to my shoutcast server.
I need to connect this address:

```
 http://s7.voscast.com:8234
```

and get response. I response is

```
GET / HTTP/1.(0|1)
```

Then again send header `pass=somePassword`

And I want to check what will be the response for pass?

Comment: What are u using to send Http Requests ?

Comment: Are you trying to make a SHOUTcast source client?  If so, it's not HTTP.

Comment: I want to broadcast from my phone. In other words, I want to use my mobile to get voice from and send to a shoutcast server. To understand this concept, I asked a question a few days ago i.e. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709739/stream-from-android-device-to-shoutcast-upstreaming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709739/stream-from-android-device-to-shoutcast-upstreaming). So I got that it uses ICY Protocal which is very similar to HTTP with some extra features. And to connect to a shoutcast server, I have to send request in headers.

Answer (score 1):

assuming that you are using import org.apache.http.client.*

it would be a simple:

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
request.setHeader("X-AUTHORIZATION", token);
```

There are also methods like setEntity:

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

            request.addHeader("X-AUTHORIZATION", token);
            request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonPost);
            request.setEntity(se);
```

see: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html